# Potentiostat circuit components

Tags: operational-amplifier

I would like to build the potentiostatic circuit in [Application Note AN-1798](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa514c/snoa514c.pdf) (Figure 2):

[image: Figure 2, AN1798]

However, I cannot determine what parts to use for Q1 and R6.

Comment: All but one resistor are 10k. That might be a good starting for R6.

Comment: Google Images has several "potentiostatic circuit".

Answer (score 2):

R6: value is not very influential, as the signal from the sensor WE terminal is expected to produce a particular current, with the op amp circuit acting to translate that current to a voltage. The op amp will adjust its output to a voltage that causes the same current to flow in R4, with the feedback action setting the op amp neg input to 0V. So output voltage will be WE current x R4 value (10k).  So actually no R6 is needed, but it's a good idea to have some resistance there which would limit current if the sensor wire for some reason contacted an untoward voltage.  1k or 10k should be fine.

The P-channel JFET is there only to create a short circuit across sensor RE and WE terminals when the circuit is powered off, as explained in the application note.  When powered on, the +V applied to the JFET input should switch it off, making it effectively disappear from the circuit.  So we want a JFET which switches on adequately with VGS = 0, and switches off adequately with VGS=12.

The JFET off characteristics are the primary concern, as leakage between D and S, or G and S would add to or subtract from the sensor current. The degree of concern depends on the current expected from the sensor, which presumably varies by application. The article discusses a 500 nA signal, in which case leakages of 5 nA constitute 1%, and 50 nA is 10%.

FWIW, the P-channel JFET, being normally on, is not nearly as popular as N-channel, so there is some lack of variety readily available.  Looking at Jameco, the 2N5460 looks like it might be good enough for < $1.  However, given the concern in the article for low-leakage ("bias current") op amps, the same concern may well apply to the JFET, so you might look for a lower-leakage JFET -- with the 2N5115 popping up as one that has significantly lower leakages (VGS-OFF 3-6V at 1nA IDS, IGSS < 500pA.  No doubt there are others.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't R6 potentially there to compensate for the concentration dependent resistance (or lack of) of the analyte as if your signal is high enough in voltage and your supply rail is low enough...in this situation a x10 gain from R4 might be beyond the voltage swing the op amp thereby saturating it after which the output voltage would be meaningless with reference to current. So with a right valued r6 you could bring the vout to a voltage below saturation voltage. Yes??

Answer (score 0):

R6 is dependant on the sensor you0re using, and usually is in the range 0 to 100 Ohm. It is there to translate the current out of WE to a voltage read by the OPAMP

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You are answering a very old question. Better participate in newer ones.